# Access local http server coming from a VM from another VM using VirtualBox

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, virtual-machine, virtualbox, freebsd

I have 2 VM running, one is giving me a local server on an address like www.x.com (FREE BSD 64bit), which I can access from my browsers locally.

My question is, if I use another VM to test with windows and IE, how can I access my www.x.com given from my other running VM with the second VM? That means, from IE?

Is that possible?

Thanks a lot, this would help me a lot, I have to deploy to our testing servers everytime I want to test something on IE and is quite annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible, of course. To connect to your VM both from host system and another VM you can set bridget networking for both VMs (BTW, maybe you already using network bridge). There are also other possibilities, but bridget network is easiest way, IMHO.

Comment: My FREE BSD has 2 network adapters enabled, first one has the NAT, and I tried the second with Bridged Netwroking and selectin the netw bridge0. Then the same steps for the Windows VM, only has one adapter, select Bridged and the same netw bridge0, but nothing happens. How should I access to the http server from my Windows VM, using the same address 'www.x.com' that I'm using locally? or I have to modify anything at hosts file from windows? thanks for your answer!

Comment: Look to the "hosts" file in your host system. If there are any mapping to "www.x.com", so then you have to implement such mapping in windows VM "hosts" file. And also you should check the IP address of Windows VM. Your host system, BSD VM and Windows VM should be in the same subnet to see each other. You must be able to ping BSD VM from windows VM.

Comment: Worked just changing the hosts file in the Windows VM, network is still NAT on it , thanks a lot! :)